# Get the index of the element in the arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get the index of `466` in the arrayList `minuteList`

```
[288, 318, 346, 376, 406, 436, 466, 1006, 1036, 1066, 1096, 1126, 1156]
```

but I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 466, Size: 13
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.pdf.PDF.refill_time_table(PDF.java:155)
    at com.pdf.PDF.main(PDF.java:54)
```

I have debugged it and the `minuteList` has the values above as well the variable `element` has the value `466`. How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
Collections.sort(diffArray);

int element = diffArray.get(diffArray.size() - 1).getElement();
int nextElement = diffArray.get(diffArray.size()-1).getNextElement();
//the error occur after this line.
minuteList.get(element);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`minuteList.get(element);` gives you the element whose index is `element`, which doesn't exist in your `ArrayList` (which only has 13 elements with indices from 0 to 12). Hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You need `minuteList.indexOf(element)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of an element with the [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) method